# Set PowerPoint grid spacing using JS API

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I am currently building an Office Add-in for PowerPoint and would like to set the grid spacing using Office JavaScript API. Is this even possible?

I looked through the corresponding API documentation but could not find any hint indicating that setting grid spacing is currently supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for that. In VBA or COM add-ins you may use the [Presentation.GridDistance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.griddistance) property which sets or returns a single that represents the distance between gridlines.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.